# Real-time video analysis on Europe server

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying out the real-time video analysis app as provided here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/cognitive-services/Computer-vision/vision-api-how-to-topics/howtoanalyzevideo_vision

More specifically, right now the LiveCameraSample. I found out it can only use WestUS server API keys, not WestEU. Is there a way to change this? I've looked into the .cs files, but no luck so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix for this has been pushed to [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Samples-VideoFrameAnalysis).  Please pull the lastest, and when you run the new app you will be presented with text fields into which you can enter the endpoint locations.

Comment: Thank you for your help!